# "if" doesn't work with "keyboard.nextLine()"

Tags: if-statement, keyboard, java.util.scanner

I would have to write the correct password and if it is correct it say "password is correct"

When I write the correct password it say that it isn't correct.

Her is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class  myclass
{
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String name;
String password;

System.out.println("give your name:\t");
name=keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.println("Hello"+name);
System.out.println("give your password:\t");
password=keyboard.nextLine();
keyboard.close();

if (password=="www")
{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("password is correct") ;
}
else 
{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("password isn't correct");        

}




}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the method equals instead of == then it will work.
Looks like that:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class myclass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        String password;

        System.out.println("give your name:\t");
        name = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hello" + name);
        System.out.println("give your password:\t");
        password = keyboard.nextLine();
        keyboard.close();

        if (password.equals( "www")) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("password is correct");
        } else {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("password isn't correct");

        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
give your name: 
name
Helloname
give your password: 
www

password is correct
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not compare `String` using `==` operator. You should use `equals` method to compare String object. e.g. `"www".equals(password)`